# How to combine multiple selectors with Adjacent sibling selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors

So I have the following combination of styles that *does* work as I want. If a button is either in `focus` or `active` state then the button's `visibility: visible;`

```
  .new-comment-button {
    margin: 0.25em 0 0.5em 0;
    float: right;
    visibility: hidden;
  }

  .new-comment-input:focus + .new-comment-button, 
  .new-comment-button:focus {
    visibility: visible;
  }

 .new-comment-input:active + .new-comment-button,
  .new-comment-button:active {
    visibility: visible;
  }
```

What I wanted to do is combine the last 2 styles into a single one that would work when the input was in a state of either `active` or `focus`. However every combination I tried failed like the following for example:

```
  .new-comment-input:focus + .new-comment-button,
  .new-comment-input:active + .new-comment-button, 
  .new-comment-button:focus {
    visibility: visible;
  }
```

I also tried:

```
  .new-comment-input:focus:active + .new-comment-button,
  .new-comment-button:focus {
    visibility: visible;
  }
```

Neither worked. I can stick with the separate styles, but I was curious is there was a way to properly combine them and account for both states of the `input`?

Comment: can you add html too or make a fiddle?

Comment: Why would that be necessary? All the OP wants to do is combine two existing, working rulesets into one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing you can do is to remove the extraneous `{ visibility: visible; }` and replace it with a comma:

```
.new-comment-input:focus + .new-comment-button, 
.new-comment-button:focus,
.new-comment-input:active + .new-comment-button,
.new-comment-button:active {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

You have four selectors split into two rulesets, but you can't combine any of them so you have to simply merge their two groups into one. `:focus:active` means both of those states at the same time (AND), not either one of them (OR), so you can't combine them that way.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `any` for this, if your targeted browsers support it:

```
.new-comment-input:any(:focus, :active) + .new-comment-button,
.new-comment-button:any(:focus, :active) {
  visibility: visible; 
}
```

At the moment, you will need to vendor prefix as `-webkit-any` etc. Eventually, this will be standardized as `:matches`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:any.

Comment: You might as well go with :matches in your code sample. Unless the OP only intends to support Gecko *xor* WebKit/Blink (God forbid), prefixing :any is counter-productive as it'd result in duplicated rules. Even the existing CSS would be DRYer then.